# Sending array from PHP to javascript through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have this php code to return many arrays to javascript through ajax.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function get_events_data() {

    // load SimpleXML
    $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('my_events.xml', null, true);

    $event_id = array();
    $channel_id = array();
    $channel_name = array();
    $channel_onclick = array();
    $event_site = array();
    $event_url = array();
    $start_date = array();
    $start_time = array();
    $end_date = array();
    $end_time = array();
    $event_notes = array();

    $n = 0;
    foreach($nodes as $node) 
    {       

        $event_id[$n] = $node['id'];               
        $channel_id[$n] = $node->channel['id'];
        $channel_name[$n] = $node->channel->name;
        $channel_onclick[$n] = $node->channel->onclick;
        $event_site[$n] = $node->event_site->name;
        $event_url[$n] = $node->event_site->url;
        $start_date[$n] = $node->start_date;
        $start_time[$n] = $node->start_time;
        $end_date[$n] = $node->end_date;
        $end_time[$n] = $node->end_time;
        $event_notes[$n] = $node->notes;
        $n++;
    }

    $return['event_id'] = $event_id;               
    $return['channel_id'] = $channel_id;
    $return['channel_name'] = $channel_name;
    $return['channel_onclick'] = $channel_onclick;
    $return['event_site'] = $event_site;
    $return['event_url'] = $event_url;
    $return['start_date'] = $start_date;
    $return['start_time'] = $start_time;
    $return['end_date'] = $end_date;
    $return['end_time'] = $end_time;
    $return['event_notes'] = $event_notes;

    echo json_encode($return);

}

echo get_events_data();

?>
```

On the javascript side I have this code to access the arrays.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_events_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (rdata) {
            var alert_data = 'event_id '+rdata.event_id[0]+'<br/>'+    
            'channel_id '+rdata.channel_id[0]+'<br/>'+
            'channel_name '+rdata.channel_name[0]+'<br/>'+
            'channel_onclick '+rdata.channel_onclick[0]+'<br/>'+
            'event_site '+rdata.event_site[0]+'<br/>'+
            'event_url '+rdata.event_url[0]+'<br/>'+
            'start_date '+rdata.start_date[0]+'<br/>'+
            'start_time '+rdata.start_time[0]+'<br/>'+
            'end_date '+rdata.end_date[0]+'<br/>'+
            'end_time '+rdata.end_time[0]+'<br/>'+
            'event_notes '+rdata.event_notes[0]+'<br/>';
            alert (alert_data);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert ("status "+status+" error "+error+"responseText "+request.responseText);
        },
});
```

When I print out the first element of each array on the javascript side, it shows as "object" doesn't show the value in that array.  What is the right way of accessing the array data on the javascript side?

Comment: Probably want to tag your question with jQuery instead of/in addition to javascript to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question showed me how to do this.  [Reading a json encoded array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611747/reading-a-json-encoded-array-in-javascript/9611765#9611765)

The json encoded rdata object returned from the PHP function could be read like this `rdata.event_id[i]["0"]`.  Here is sample code for the objects within rdata.

```
 var event = rdata.event_id[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.channel_name[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.channel_onclick[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.event_site[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.event_url[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.event_onclick[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.start_date[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.start_time[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.end_date[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.end_time[i]["0"]+' '+
                    rdata.event_notes[i]["0"]+' ';
                    $('#event_list').append(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, an associative array is pretty much an object. Your script is working correctly. Do a `console.log()` with your data and explore how it prints out in the console, then use that to access the data. You could also post up the JSON data in question and probably get more detailed answers.

Comment: An an associative array is not "pretty much an object".  An associative array is an object in javascript.  More correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your 'similar' code:

```
foreach($nodes as $node) 
{       
    $event_id[] = $node['id'];               
    $channel_id[] = $node->channel['id'];
    $channel_name[] = $node->channel->name;
    $channel_onclick[] = $node->channel->onclick;
    $event_site[] = $node->event_site->name;
    $event_url[] = $node->event_site->url;
    $start_date[] = $node->start_date;
    $start_time[] = $node->start_time;
    $end_date[] = $node->end_date;
    $end_time[] = $node->end_time;
    $event_notes[] = $node->notes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to either `echo`

```
echo json_encode($return);
```

or

```
echo get_events_data();
```

better:

```
echo json_encode($return);
} // end of function
```

then next line

```
get_events_data();
```