# Reading a json encoded array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This php function returns a json encoded object to a javascript through ajax. I create a variable with this json object with stringify.

```
var event_id = JSON.stringify(rdata.event_id);
```

When I print that variable it looks like this.

```
[{"0":"e20111129215359"},{"0":"e20120301133826"},{"0":"e20120301184354"},{"0":"e20120301193226"},{"0":"e20120301193505"},{"0":"e20120303182807"},{"0":"e20120303205512"},{"0":"e20120303211019"},{"0":"e20120306182514"},{"0":"e20120307122044"}]
```

How do I access each element of event_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `stringify` it. It's already a valid JavaScript object, so just access it directly with:

```
rdata.event_id[0]["0"];
// e20111129215359

// Or read them in a loop
for (var i=0; i<rdata.event_id.length; i++) {
   console.log(rdata.event_id[i]["0"];
}
```

The value `rdata.event_id` is an array `[]` containing a bunch of object literals `{}` each having just one property `"0"`. Since the property is a number instead of a string, you need to use the `["0"]` syntax to access it, rather than the normal object dot operator.