# Get elements of json_encoded array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

i passed a `json_encode`d array to javascript. Now i would like to acces that array to get the different elemtnts.

i print it out in the `console.log()` and i get this array:

```
array(1) {
  [16]=>
  array(2) {
    [3488]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["article_no_internal"]=>
        string(6) "999184"
        ["article_name_internal"]=>
        string(29) "Geschenkbox Kerzenschein 2011"
      }
    }
    [2615]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["article_no_internal"]=>
        string(6) "700469"
        ["article_name_internal"]=>
        string(29) "Hotelscheck RomantischeTagef2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is about right. How can i access the article_name of the second array, with the ID 2615?

found a related question here [reading a jsone object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611747/reading-a-json-encoded-array-in-javascript), hope for some better explebation or answer. Thanks.

EDIT:

As it seems i made a mistake, i showed a php var_dump in the console. When i try to show the javascript array in the console i get undefined.

Comment: You get that output from `console.log`?! That looks like `var_dump` in PHP. How exactly are you passing that array?

Comment: @deceze you are right it was a lost var_dump in php. Now it seems i dont have anything in my console this is how i encode: `$shipping_part_list_array = json_encode($db_obj->getArticleList($elements),true);` and how i pass to javascript: `var array = <?php echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>;` in the console now i have undefined.

Comment: if i go like this `var array = <?php echo  json_encode($shipping_part_list_array); ?>;` it says there are no childe objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JSON means "JavaScript Object Notation" you don't need to do anything to access the object's items.

For example you can access:

```
jsonObject[2615][0]["article_name_internal"]
```

if this object is String, use `eval` to convert the string to a JavaScript object and access the items in the same way with the previous example.

```
var jsonObject = eval(jsonstring);
jsonObject[2615][0]["article_name_internal"]
```

Comment: `json_encode($db_obj->getArticleList($elements),true);` this is how i encode in php `var array = <?php echo $shipping_part_list_array; ?>;` and like this i pass the array, but when i `console.log(array);` i just get undefined prototype.